# MYSQL Update Column Based on Rounded Average of Other Columns in Row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update one column based on the rounded average of four other columns in the same row.

Here's what the table looks like:

+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+------------+---------------+

| member_id | level_id | friendliness | activity | popularity | participation |
+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+------------+---------------+

|   1017895 |        4 |            7 |        5 |          4 |             4 |

+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+------------+---------------+

Here's how I attempted to do this at first:

```
UPDATE member_levels SET level_id = 
ROUND(AVG(friendliness+activity+popularity+participation)) 
WHERE member_id = '1017895';
```

The above gave me the error: Invalid use of group function

So, I did a search on Stack Overflow and found this 
[MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Based on the above, I tried doing a nested subquery like this:

```
UPDATE member_levels m1 SET m1.level_id = 
 (SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT ROUND(AVG(friendliness+activity+popularity+participation)) 
     FROM member_levels m2 
     WHERE m2.member_id = m1.member_id)a
  ) 
WHERE m1.member_id = '1017895';
```

But that gave me the error:  Unknown column 'm1.member_id' in 'where clause'

Then I found this question on Stack Overflow: [Update column with average calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771815/update-column-with-average-calculation)

So, based on that question, I tried this:

```
UPDATE member_levels m1, 
  (SELECT 
   ROUND(AVG(m2.friendliness+m2.activity+m2.popularity+m2.participation))
   rounded_avg 
   FROM member_levels m2 
   WHERE m2.member_id  = m1.member_id
  ) s 
SET m1.level_id = s.rounded_avg 
WHERE m1.member_id = '1017895';
```

Again, that attempt gave me the error: Unknown column 'm1.member_id' in 'where clause'

What am I missing? How can I update level_id based on the rounded average of friendliness, activity, popularity, and participation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `AVG` doesn't work as you assume. Take a look at the [manual, AVG](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg). It doesn't take your 4 columns, sums their values and divides the result by 4. It calculates the average of all rows ...

Comment: Not tested: `ROUND(CAST((friendliness + activity + popularity + participation) AS DOUBLE) / 4.0) rounded_avg` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVG` is for **row** average on a grouping (aggregate).

If you need to manually average multiple **columns**.. assuming it's a fixed # of columns this would work:

```
ROUND((friendliness+activity+popularity+participation) / 4)
```